# Keep showing popupWindow when back button of keyboard is pressed

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am working on an Android application and I've designed a popupWindow to show some view by replacing a soft keyboard in an activity. The popupWindow contains a searchView. When I click on a button, it shows the popupWindow and the soft keyboard gets hidden. Now when the searchView in the popupWindow gets focus, I call the method:

> popupWindow.setFocusable(true)

To show keyboard so that users can start typing in searchView. When the searchView is in focus and the soft keyboard is open, then pressing the back key closes both the searchView and the popupWindow as well.

To solve this issue, I created a **custom searchView** and overrode the method **dispatchKeyEventPreIme** in this as below.

```
public class CustomSearchView extends SearchView {

    Context context;
    AppConstant mAppConst;

    public CustomSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {

       if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
           clearFocus();
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
    }
}
```

I have cleared the focus from the searchView when the back button is pressed, but I don't know how can I prevent the popupWindow from closing.

[image]

Comment: try this .. popupWindow.setCancelable(false)

Comment: @MeenalSharma popupWindow deosn't have `setCancelable` method. `AlertDialog` and `Dialog` does.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I tried and it worked!

In onCreate():

```
private PopupWindow popupWindow;

someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) appContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow_view, null, false);

        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);

        CustomSearchView searchView = (CustomSearchView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.customSearchView);
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(someButton, 50, -30);
    }
});
```

Make sure to have this in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (popupWindow != null && popupWindow.isShowing()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Activity Back Pressed - PopupWindow showing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

My XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.package.name.CustomSearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/customSearchView"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></com.package.name.CustomSearchView>

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomSearchView.java

```
public class CustomSearchView extends SearchView {

    Context context;

    public CustomSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
       if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
           clearFocus();
           Toast.makeText(context, "CustomSearchView Back Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return false;
       } else {
           return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
       }
    }
}
```

When I do this implementation, CustomSearchView's `dispatchKeyEventPreIme` does not called BUT Activity's `OnBackPressed()` does get called.

As you see, I put a `Toast` when back button gets pressed and it calls each time. Try it out. It doesn't close the PopupWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your Activity. If popupWindow is showing, back button won't do anything.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (popupWindow != null && popupWindow.isShowing()) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

You can also use this feature so when clicked outside of popupWindow, it won't close.

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

/// UPDATE

Try changing this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       clearFocus();
       return false;
    } else {
       return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already done this in the below way. 

`popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
popup.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
popup.setOutsideTouchable(false);`

OnBackPressed in the activity is not getting called when I press back button on soft keyboard, so I've created custom SearchView and detecting back button in the **dispatchKeyEventPrime**
But I am not getting any way in which I can stop popupWindow dismissal. Please help, if you know how to achieve it. It would be a great help. Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Ok that's fine but what about the `onBackPressed()` of the `Activity`? That's what back key triggers

Comment: Activity's Backpress is not getting called when back button is pressed when soft keyboard is open.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. change `dispatchKeyEventPreIme`. I made a mistake. made another change

Comment: Ok, I am checking this solution and will update you.

Comment: Sorry to say but it's not working :( What else I can do ?

Comment: umm interesting. Im gonna try out ur scenario. I will let u know soon

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :) It would be a great help :)

Comment: Check my new answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts to solve this problem. Actually I want to design a view same like Facebook does to show stickers. I've already done that but my issue is with the searchView which I am not able to solve. I have added a screenshot in my above question. Please check once and let me know if you can help me in any way here. Thanks a lot for all your efforts :)