# How to disable back button when popup window dialog is showing?

Tags: android

I have a popup window with an `EditText` input inside. Creation of the popup window looks like this:

`Boolean focusable = true;
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);`

This all works well and the `EditText` can by typed into. The problem arises when the user clicks the back button on the android phone. The back button dismisses the popup window. This should not happen since the intention was the user cannot proceed until an interaction with the popup is made.

Now, we can certainly set the focusability of the popup view to `false` to prohibit dismissing via the back button:

`Boolean focusable = false;
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);`

The problem here now is the `EditText` does not receive the focus it needs to be able to type. Hence, the user cannot interact with the `EditText`

Any idea how I can solve this problem, either through the popup view or the `EditText`?

EDIT:

So I tried to override the `onBackPress` method on the main activity with a logger to check whether the listener is called in the activity:

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Logger.d("isthistriggered");
        finish();
    }
```

It turns out, the `onBackPressed` is not called when the popup is alive. Once you press the back button the second time, it triggers the listener.

Comment: does your pop-up also dismisses when you click outside it's scope ?

Comment: @Umair the popup covers the whole view, so there is no opportunity to click outside of scope

Comment: Please check my answer if it works for you. quick leaner's answer will actually dismiss the popup window.

Answer (score 2):

place static method `removePopupWindow(view v)` in **MainActivity**,
 and call it inside `onBackPressed()` like `MainActivity.removePopupWindow(popWindow);`

Answer (score 1):

The `onBackPressed` won't be delivered to the `Activity` immediately if PopupWindow is being displayed, hence any effort for Overriding it and performing action would be futile. One way to achieve it is to create your CustomView and Override `dispatchKeyEventPreIme()`. You can follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595131/keep-showing-popupwindow-when-back-button-of-keyboard-is-pressed) which describes this approach.

Comment: That seems to be true from the tests. I'll check it out thanks.

Comment: would you know of a way to make the inside of the `PopupWindow` focusable while the outside is not? (i.e. the `EditText` problem)

Comment: AFAIK its not possible. But I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks it looks like the CustomView would probably the path to go then. Or perhaps I'm implementing it using the wrong construct (`PopupView`) since it requires input. Do you think this would be easier if I just made it part of the layout and then hide, unhide it instead?

Answer (score -1):

You have to handle back button press when dialog is showing

**Just override the** `onBackPressed()` **in your activity**

**And Declare the popup window object globally**

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (popupWindow != null && popupWindow.isShowing()) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using PopupWindow element. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow. Where should I place the `onBackPressed` here, the activity that triggers the popupWindow?

Comment: yes in activity you have to override onBack pressed and declare popup window object globally

Comment: try this and let me know if it works or not , i am waiting

Comment: Tried it out. And it doesn't trigger the `OnBackPressed` when backbutton is clicked and the popup is dismissed. It's triggered after the popup gets dismissed and you click the back button again.

Comment: I just tried out the logs to see if it triggers the `onBackPressed`. 

`
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Logger.d("isthistriggered");
        finish();
    }
`

Comment: Sorry it looks bad, I was trying to add it in a gist. I'll add in the question. thanks